# Hide react-tooltip after certain time

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-tooltip module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip),

Cannot figure out how to hide a tiiltip after a certain time (5 seconds for instance)

I tried this:

```
<ReactTooltip afterShow={() => { setTimeout(ReactTooltip.hide(), 5000) }} />
```

But in this case tooltip will not even showup

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use parentheses `()` after method, just put a link of the method like this:

```
setTimeout(ReactTooltip.hide, 5000)
```

But in this case tooltip will not even show up because your method `ReactTooltip.hide()` is invoked immediately after tooltip is shown