# how to create a tooltip which is open after click of a div and it remove after few second in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

how to create a tooltip which is open after the click of a div and it removes after few second in react JS

Comment: when click to set tooltip visible.tooptip plugins link:https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide react-tooltip after certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785243/hide-react-tooltip-after-certain-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify

I hope I was helpfull